# What is the definition if a distinct cycle in a graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

In a graph, I understand a cycle to be a traversal from Node A, traversing each (but not every) vertex once, and returning to Node A. Now I THINK a distinct cycle is where they don't share any vertices, but I might be wrong. Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: No matter what the mathematical objects in question, ‘$x$ and $y$ are distinct widgets’ normally means simply that $x$ and $y$ are widgets, and $x\ne y$. You’re thinking of vertex-disjoint cycles; one can also have edge-disjoint cycles and cycles that are disjoint in both senses.

Comment: So you're saying, for example the Cycle S = {2,3,4,5,2} and Cycle P = {2,3,4,2} are distinct because S /= P?

Comment: Yes, as the word *distinct* is normally used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanding the comment by Brian M. Scott): being distinct is not a property of a cycle, but a relation between two cycles. Two cycles are distinct if they are not the same cycle.

[Usage example](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Hamilton_Cycles_in_Complete_Graph): "For all $n\ge 3$, the number of distinct Hamilton cycles in the complete graph $K_n$ is $(n−1)!/2$."

[Related story from MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53905):

> Q: "Are the groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ isomorphic?"
>   A: "$G_1$ is, but $G_2$ isn't."